# Spotfire updating data on demand table

Tags: python, spotfire

I need to update a data on demand data table on spotfire. Is there a way to do it over script? I have looked into multiple pages to use the refresh function, but it doesn't seem to work either through the script or when I do it manually through the data table properties. Here are the links that i looked at:

[Spotfire: Create button to start loading data ,instead of using load data on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925626/spotfire-create-button-to-start-loading-data-instead-of-using-load-data-on-dem)

https://datashoptalk.com/trigger-on-demand-queries-ironpython/

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-refresh-or-reload-data-using-ironpython-script-tibco-spotfire.

Here is my code that I used, in case I am missing something.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataManager,DataTable
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Scripting import ScriptDefinition
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary,List
from System.Collections import ArrayList
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import NotificationService
import clr

table=List[DataTable]()
table.Add(Document.Data.Tables["test"])
Document.Data.Tables.Refresh(table)
```

The version of spotfire that I am using is 7.11. The main issue that the selection on the main data table does not affect the data on demand tables at all. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am not sure if this was updated in future versions, but I got a response from the company saying that mine would not be able to do it. The way I got around it was creating a marking that was only being used to update the data on demand tables from the original table. I then created a script to update these markings to match the marking that I was using normally. This way you can still mark things on the table and then have a button that will update the data on demand tables individually. It is important that each data on demand table gets its own marking that will be updated through the script.

Answer (score 0):

The script looks good and it should work as expected. however, when you use the script to reload the on-demand table just make sure that the checkbox - "Load automatically" and "Allow caching" are unchecked in on-Demand Settings.

Regards,
Ankush

Comment: is there a way to change those settings for an already exsisting table. I cant seem to find it unless I create a new data table

Comment: Yes, there is a way - Goto **Edit** -> **Data Table Properties** ->, In **General**, you can see an option **Type of data** -> **Settings** on the right that is the on-Demand Settings and you can find "Load automatically" and "Allow caching" at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. I think I am using  a different version than you, because I could not find these settings. I put up my solution, which is a roudabout way to do it.